# What is the norm in the definition of the projective norm?

Tags: banach-spaces

The projective norm is definied as:
$\pi(u)=\inf\left\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|x_n\|\|y_n\|:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \|x_n\|\|y_n\|<\infty,\, u = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n \otimes y_n \right\}$,
what are the norms $ \|x_n\|$ and $\|y_n\|$?